# prevent of unicode character in textbox

Tags: jquery

hi i have some textbox in a form n i wanna one of them can only get symbol number and english character but prevent of unicode like ب or ن orص and ....

i wrote following code but it did not work

```
 $(function () {

        $("#usernametxt").keydown(function (event) {

            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9) {

            }
            else {

                 if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <=90) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105))
                 {

                 }

                else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }

        })

    })
```

when i wrote fllowing code all of the text box coulnot get unicode

```
 document.onkeypress = function (evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
        var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        if (/[a-zA-Z0-9-_*() #@ ]/i.test(charStr)) {

        }
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
```